# Android Intent Error

Tags: android, android-intent

I got problem in inflate. Someone can help?

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    ((Object) getMenuInflater()).inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: in  ((Object) getMenuInflater()).inflate(R.menu.main, menu); I test in getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu); but .inflate incorrect

Answer (score 1):

Hope this help to understand.

```
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
```